# Objective C Equivalent code for Swift initialization of iZettles library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to upgrade `iZettle/sdk-ios` to latest version which is 3.0.1.
But this also required changes in library initialization code for Swift here:
https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-ios

There is 5. Initialize the SDK code with Swift example. I need same in Objective C.I am new to iOS, so this is hard for me. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is the code for which I need obj-C version:

```
let authenticationProvider = try iZettleSDKAuthorization(
    clientID: "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
    callbackURL: URL(string: "app-scheme://url"))

iZettleSDK.shared().start(with: authenticationProvider)
```

I have been looking for this for a day, but was not able to find.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you're still looking for an Objective-C initialization code of that library while there's already one in the sample from the repo that you just mentioned.

https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-ios/blob/master/Example/Sample/iZettleSDKSample/AppDelegate.m

See that `AppDelegate.m` in the sample project. It uses though a custom provider.

---

But to convert that sample pieces of code you have to Objective-C can be a bit tricky.

You should have something like this:

```
    NSError *error;
    id<iZettleSDKAuthorizationProvider> authorizationProvider = [[iZettleSDKAuthorization alloc]
                                                                 initWithClientID:clientId
                                                                 callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callbackURL]
                                                                 error:&error
                                                                 enforcedUserAccount:^NSString * _Nullable{
        return [AccountManager shared].enforcedUserAccount;
    }];

    NSAssert(!error, @"%@", error.description);

[[iZettleSDK shared] startWithAuthorizationProvider:authorizationProvider];
```

I suggest by the way to look at the basic syntax of both Swift and Objective-C. Knowing both languages can be crucial if you want to dive deep into iOS engineering.